# I have three cpp file.I want test that template class declaration and definition in different file.but i got failed

Tags: c++

this is my code snnippet

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
int main(){
  Test<int> test = Test<int>();

  test.add(1);
  test.print();
}

// test.h
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST
template <typename T> class Test{
public:
  T info;
  void print();
  void add(T i);
 };
#endif
// testT.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

template<typename T> void Test<T>::print()
{
   std::cout << info << std::endl;
}
template<typename T> void Test<T>::add(T i)
{
  info = i;
}
```

and i run this exec

```
g++ -c testT.cpp && g++ test.cpp -o a.out testT.o
```

i get this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test<int>::add(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-e89092.o
  "Test<int>::print()", referenced from:
      _main in test-e89092.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  // in my macOS
```

i want to declare template class in head file and define method in other file,so i only compile the define method file not head file if i change the definition of method in template class. what should i do?

Comment: post your code and your error here as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: @Zinki i have reedited it

Answer (score 0):

A posible way to seperate template to cpp and header is to typedef it to the types you are using it from the source which define the functions bodies.

for example: in your code, if you'll add a `typedef Test<int> __UNUSED_TEMP_INT__;` in the bottom of testT.cpp it will compiled for `int` in a place it recognize the bodies. but than you can use the template only for `int`.

Other option is to include the source from the header, but then the cpp is just another header.